# Writing application with a calendar feed

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I am writing an application that provides a calendar feed for people to subscribe to. Changes may be made to the calendar feed up to moments before the event occurs, and it would be really nice if those changes could be propagated out to all subscribers when this happens.

The only solution I have today is to provide an iCal format so that people can add it to their Google calendars (the most popular for my target audience), but Google calendar seems to be especially slow to notice changes.

Is there a way to force Google calendar to re crawl my url if a change occurs?

Is there another way to provide a calendar feed to people that may work better for my needs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what technology you are using, but have a look at the [Google Calendar Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/).

> The Calendar Data API lets you incorporate Calendar functionality into your own application or website. You can edit calendars, create and delete events, send invitations, and more.